# SwiftUI - edgesIgnoringSafeArea behaves differently in iOS 13.4

Tags: swiftui

I've noticed that in my app .edgesIgnoringSafeArea renders my view differently in iOS 13.3 vs. iOS 13.4.

In my ContentView I have a modifier of .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top) applied. This displayed correctly in all iOS 13 versions leading up to 13.4. Now in the GM of 13.4 the top and bottom of the view is getting cut off.

Here's my ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
func getUser() {
    session.listen()
}



var body: some View {

        Group {
            ZStack {
                TabView {
                    ExploreView().tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                        Text("Explore")
                    }.tag(1)
                    FestivalsView().tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "globe")
                        Text("Festivals")
                    }.tag(2)
                    ProfileView().tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.fill")
                        Text("Profile")
                    }.tag(3)
                }
                .accentColor(Color("wdwPurple"))
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
        }.onAppear(perform: getUser)
    }
}
```

Here's how it displays:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the reason for ZStack and Group in your code?

Comment: I would say that on 13.3 is incorrect - it is exactly does not ignore top safe area. Ignoring is fine for background, in your case - text - I would not use this modifier at all.

Comment: I have the same issue. On device. The app looked good on iOS 13.3 and now it's all broken like yours after iOS 13.4 update.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Neither of the answers below make any sense. If we "correct" this for iOS 13.4, it will break everything from iOS 13.3 down.

Comment: I pushed a new build of my app with the modifier removed and it displays correctly on iOS 13.3.1 and 13.4. But yeah, that was my fear too thinking that if I fixed it for 13.4 it would break anything below that.

Comment: I'm afraid I can confirm this behavior on my device since iOS 13.4, at least with the `.top` edge.  With the modifier, navigation bars extend well into the status bar.  Without, the status bar remains solid while content scrolls beneath translucent nav bars.

Comment: After some debugging, I learned that the issue may have something to do with my mix of UIKit and SwiftUI views and view controllers. After changing tabs, my `UIViewController` decides it doesn't need to extend beneath the status bar as it should, while my SwiftUI views handle it fine.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, on iOS GM 13.4 look like is correct, because is ignore top safe area

Answer (score 0):

I removed the modifier and it seemed to display correctly. Like other people have said, the simulator isn't a great indicator of how things actually render on an actual device.